# problems with my Python code connecting with google docs api

Tags: python, api, automation, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm coding a Python app to automatize invoices via a google docs API but I'm having errors with the code and I don't know how to solve it

```
    # [START docs_quickstart]
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']



def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    

        title = 'My Document'
        body = {
        'title': title
                }
        document = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
        print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
        document.get('title')))
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)
    

    
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# [END docs_quickstart]
```

and this is the error code that I'm having

```
PS D:\Universidad\Proyectos de Programacion Propia\python\googledocsinvoice.restapi> python quickstart.py
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'docs.googleapis.com', 'method': 'google.apps.docs.v1.DocumentsService.CreateDocument'}}]">
```

if you know some guide or complete tutorial to Automate Document Creation with the Google Docs API like invoices and replace encapsulation values like {{productID}} I will be very grateful
I saw the Automate document creation of google channel but it wasn't very helpful https://youtu.be/-dX-fWb3ogE

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you also enable the Docs API in your Developers Console.
2. Delete the credential file `~/.credentials.json` and `token.json` (if you ran the code before
3. Change the scope variable used for reading docs

`var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly'];`

to

`var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents'];`

Check more info on https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create#authorization-scopes and https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/authorizing

3. After the execution of code, API will authenticate again and then the issue should be resolved.